# iOS 14 Widget on TestFlight or Release build configuration on Xcode 12 beta 6 not working?

Tags: widgetkit

I am experiencing an error in my app with the new widgets. It works perfectly in debug mode, both in simulator and in physical device. But when I upload the version to app connect the widget appears frozen, only with the default data.

I have changed: (Without success)
ENABLEBITCODE to NO,
STRIPSTYLE to Non-Global Symbols,
DEADCODESTRIPPING to No

When I run the app in release mode in the simulator it throws me this message:

Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '/Users/oskarsmacx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyPempi's-bcfexbgdkgfsmaeniruefdnmjbul/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Pempi's.app'- using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.

Any ideas?

Comment: This might be irrelevant but you cannot have an apostrophe in your app name.

Comment: I know, which is why excode is smart enough and actually names it Pempi-s. In the error it appears with an apostrophe because it is only the path with its name.

Comment: In Xcode's Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme, there's a field called *LLDB Init File*. It sounds like maybe your field is empty? I dunno, just a thought.